# How do i copy a Json file from the Assets/Resources/ to the Internal storage of an Android device ( persistent data)? [Unity Android]

Tags: android, json, unity-game-engine, assets, android-assets

I want to copy a single json file from `Unity's Assets/Resources/` directory to the internal persistent memory of Android device (`INTERNAL STORAGE/Android/data/<packagename>/files/`) only once at the start of the game. I looked up all over the internet, with solutions saying to use Streaming assets and UnityWebRequests or WWW class which is obsolete now. I tried everything for hours now. And did not find a exact solutions, but only got null references and directory not found.

I added my json file to the `<UnityProject>/Assets/Resources/StreamingAssets/`, but it doesn't seem to detect any streaming assets. I understand an apk is a zip file and so I can only read the contents of streaming assets, but my I can't find a solution to this.

Once I get my json from streaming asset, I can finally add it to `Application.persistentDataPath`.

**UPDATE**
I had actually figured it out,

```
     public void LoadFromResources() {
 {mobilePath = "StreamingAssets/"; mobilePath = mobilePath + "stickerJson" + ".json";
 string newPath = mobilePath.Replace(".json", "");
 TextAsset ta = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(newPath);
 string json = ta.text; Debug.Log(json); System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/stickers.json", json);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy a file you only need to have the information of the file and then create a new one in another place.

So if you got your json file into your Resources directory you can retreive like the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html?_ga=2.212238356.1462135184.1590497504-1751818090.1485189056) say:

```
//Load text from a JSON file (Assets/Resources/Text/jsonFile01.json)
var jsonTextFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Text/jsonFile01");
//Then use JsonUtility.FromJson<T>() to deserialize jsonTextFile into an object
```

Then you only have to create your android file in your persistentDataPath as @Iggy says in the comments doing:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "file.txt"), jsonTextFile);
```

*Note: Not really sure, but for other cases I think that StreamingAssets folder should be inside Assets, no inside Resources.*

Comment: And to create the file you'd do: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "file.txt"), jsonTextFile);`